# PHP: remove BOM at the very beginning of the file

Tags: php, amp-html, byte-order-mark

I'm using AMP with PHP and when I'm trying the AMP validator (ttps://validator.ampproject.org/) I get a couple of errors that do not make sense become of a BOM character at the beginning of my page.

Example:

URL: https://www.laurentwillen.be/gadgets/xiaomi-redmi-note-7-test-avis-et-prix/

I get the following error: (among others)

The mandatory attribute '⚡' is missing in tag 'html'
If you look at the source of this page, the attribute is there but when you use the AMP validator, there is a red dot appearing at the very beginning of my page.

If I add a letter at the very top of my code like this:

```
A
<?PHP
// my code goes here
?>
```

I see the red dot appearing before the letter which highlights that my code is not generating the issue. In Notepad++ I see that the encoding is set to UTF8.

Do you know how I could remove this so that I can work on the real AMP errors?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: *"In Notepad++ I see that the encoding is set to UTF8."* - Is that with or without BOM?

Comment: It is set to UTF8 only, there is UTF8 with BOM right below but it's not selected

Comment: Ok. Hm.... hard to say what the problem could be. Try to save the file as a copy of it, then "convert" it to UTF8 without BOM from the dropdown and resave.

Comment: If there are any included files or JS etc, then that also could be an issue.

Comment: indeed but even if I remove all the calls to other files, the problem still appears.